# This SQL statement is what I wanted, but why?

Tags: sql, database

I was trying to figure out a SQL statement for selecting the employee "name and salary" that matches a certain position in the salary amount, being the highest salary; second highest; and so forth.

After some research I found the simplest one that works.

But I'm not sure I understand why.

Here it is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (2-1) = (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
FROM Employee Emp2
WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```

Replacing the "2" in the WHERE statement with whatever position I want works.

But I'm not sure why.

I get that COUNT will return the amount of rows.
And DISTINCT returns only values where the values are different.

It's just that a lot of the other solutions included using MAX.

How does this statement that I provided actually find the exact position like I was expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery is a correlated subquery.

It is counting the number of `salary` values that are strictly larger than the salary on a given row.

- If the given row has the highest salary, then the `count()` returns `0`.  There are no higher salaris.
- If the given row has the second highest salary, then the `count()` returns `1` -- the highest salary.
- And so on.

Set the comparison to be the value that you want.  Your logic is subtracting `1`, so you can put in `1` for the highest (and the result is `0`.  By the way, you could change this to:

```
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Emp2.Salary)
           FROM Employee Emp2
           WHERE Emp2.Salary >= Emp1.Salary
-----------------------------^ >= vs >
          )
```

This counts the salary itself, so the pesky `- 1` is not needed.